# Why my string interpolation is not working with URL?

Tags: node.js, string

I am making a react app and my string interpolation is not working. It's a bit strange because it is not working in URL or links.
I am trying to complete a link here but I tried to check using a variable and it is working otherwise but not in links.
I am having issue with ${number} part in backgroundImage
Can anyone help with this as I am stuck?[This is the snippet of the code where I am having issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbPSD.png)

Comment: please post code, not images of code ... And for string interpolation to work, you need to enclose the string in backticks `\`` and not single `'` or double `"` quotes

Comment: @daddygames for ES6 string interpolation you need backticks and curly braces

Comment: Doh... I was just looking at a Flutter post before this and confused myself... Scratch that comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing backticks around the string you're trying to interpolate

Wrap this string: URL('....${number})' in backticks, backtick: `

Comment: Your syntax is off (at time of writing). `\`URL('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${number}')\``

Comment: FYI use \\` to use backticks in a code snippet

Comment: Got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by concatinating URL with searchValue and then adding the remaining part of url, here's a example:

```
let searchValue="lahore"; 
let url='https://api.RandomWebsite.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+ searchValue + '&appid=API_KEY';
```